# Getting part of string using jQuery .search results in null

Tags: jquery

I need to extract the page number from URL string similar to:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?paged=2
```

I am able to retrieve the same using:

```
page_number = this.search.match(/paged=(\d+)/)[1];
```

This gives me "2" as result. However, at times the URL does not contain any page number, like:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php
```

This is where the problem crops up. jQuery throws the error `this.search.match(/paged=(\d+)/) is null`. How do I overcome the null error? I do not find a method to check for null. Also I have tried `if((this.search.match(/paged=(\d+)/)[1]).length > 0 )`. But this also results in the same error.

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the equality operator (`==`) to check against the value `null`.

```
var match = this.search.match(/paged=(\d+)/);

if (match !== null) {
    var page_number = match[1];

    // do stuff with page_number
}
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. This works! I was directly checking the array index for null. Whereas, I should have checked the array as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gup method, which is described [here](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html).

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. I have gone with Matt's answer which suits my purpose. Moreover, I am dealing with strings that merely have URLs in them. If I understand it correctly from window.location.href in your example, it deals with URLs in browser. Something I am not intending to do.